# Android on Netbook

Tags: android, netbook

I have Asus eeepc netbook and want Android either Ecliar or Froyo or Gingerbreads. I can't get .apks to work yet. Do I need to partion first?

Friend says you guys know everything.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

This [guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/22665/run-android-on-your-netbook-or-desktop/) at how-to geek is very informative. Basically, partition, download OS, install with a USB or memory card

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.